# Creating a column with row number when another column value changes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
package_num   delivery_date
122           12/21
122           12/21
134           12/30
156           12/30
156           12/30
```

I want to be able to do use something like MySQL row_number() but on python. I want a column of row number that starts with 1 and goes up increments of 1 until package number changes. So my desired outcome is:

```
package_num   delivery_date    row_number
122           12/21            1
122           12/21            2
134           12/30            1
156           12/30            1
156           12/30            2
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit extended version using list comprehension:

```
val = df.groupby('package_num').count().values.ravel()
df['row_numer'] = [j  for i in val for j in range(1, i+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumcount()` , like this

```
df['row_number']= df.groupby('package_num').cumcount()+1


package_num   delivery_date    row_number
122           12/21            1
122           12/21            2
134           12/30            1
156           12/30            1
156           12/30            2
```

Comment: groupby should be applied on "package_num" column

Comment: @ErnestSKirubakaran Oh right, thanks